# Server Sent Event and pg_notify with React and Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm having some troubles when I refresh my front-end with F5.

Suppose I refresh six times my view, then when something triggers my table in PostgreSQL, pg_notify notifies six times that something has changed.

This is my code in React:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    const sse = new EventSource('http://localhost:3005/orders/notification');

    sse.onmessage = event => {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
      setNewPizza(prevNotification => {
        if (typeof(prevNotification[0]) === 'string') {
          return parsedData
        } else {
          const newArr = parsedData.concat(prevNotification)
          return newArr
        }
      })
    };

    sse.onerror = () => {
      alert('Something wrong with notifications.')
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = () => {
      console.log('Closing connection')
      sse.close();
    };

    return () => {
      window.onbeforeunload = () => {
        console.log('Closing connection')
        sse.close();
      };
    };
  }, []);
```

And this is my Route :

```
router.get('/notification', async (req, res, next) => {
    
    try {
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type'  : 'text/event-stream',
        'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',
        'Connection'    : 'keep-alive',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
      };

      res.writeHead(200, headers);

      const config = {
        user: DB.PGUSER,
        host: DB.PGHOST,
        database: DB.PGDATABASE,
        password: DB.PGPASSWORD,
        port: DB.PGPORT,
      }

      const client = new Client(config);

      await client.connect();
  
      await client.query('LISTEN paid_products');

      client.on('notification', async data => {
        const payload = JSON.parse(data.payload);
        const stmt = `
         SELECET * FROM table_1;
        `;
        results = await db.query(stmt);
        res.write('id: 123456789\n');
        res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(results.rows)}\n\n`);
      })

    } catch (err) {
      next(err)
    }
    
  });
```

Probably is because with each refresh (F5), my Route is loading again and with that `client.on('notification', async data => {...}` too. So that's why my pg_notify it is triggered many times. However, in React I'm just getting one data, not many data as refreshes.

I tried to fix it putting `client.on('notification', async data => {...}` inside an if condition to run it just one time, and that fix the problem. But then, `res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(results.rows)}\n\n`);` is not sending the information.

```
if (firstTime) {

        config = {
          user: DB.PGUSER,
          host: DB.PGHOST,
          database: DB.PGDATABASE,
          password: DB.PGPASSWORD,
          port: DB.PGPORT,
        }
        client = new Client(config);
  
        await client.connect();
    
        await client.query('LISTEN paid_pizzas');

        client.on('notification', async data => {
          const payload = JSON.parse(data.payload);
            const stmt = `
              SELECT * FROM table_1;
            `;
            results = await db.query(stmt);
            // return results.rows;
            res.write('id: 123456789\n');
            res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(results.rows)}\n\n`);
          })
   }

        firstTime = false;
```

=( Don't know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those who encounter this problem! I solve it using [express-sse](https://github.com/dpskvn/express-sse). With that library, there is no need to pass "res" down to `client.on('notification', async data => {...})`, instead you pass down `sse` and use `sse.send(content)` inside `client.on()`.

However, there is one more library needed. Which is [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#server-sent-events), there you can see that the example is not using [express-sse](https://github.com/dpskvn/express-sse), instead it is using `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream') res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')`. Inside [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#server-sent-events) watch this  `// !!! this is the important part res.flush()`.

Without [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#server-sent-events) for my case there was this error: `TypeError: res.flush is not a function at SSE.dataListener`. So use [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#server-sent-events).

You can read this page for more details: [How to use SSE in the best way possible](https://ably.com/topic/server-sent-events#how-to-use-sse-in-the-best-way-possible). It helped me a lot.

And of course, I took out `client.on('notification', async data => {...})` of my router, which it was being called with each refresh by react.